# Pandas: interpolate between column values to return index name

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.6

I'd like to return the `index name` and `cost` in the following code. I think I'm on the right track, but not sure how to push this forward, I've attached my code and output

**EDIT:** I'm open to design changes in the way I'm doing this.

for example `a` in `test_data`, it should return `'a': 'rep_asp_art', '1000000'`

```
import pandas as pd


treatments = {'min_asp_art': {'treat': 'min', 'mat': 'asp', 'class': 'art',
                              'hci': 85, 'cost': 100000},
              'maj_asp_art': {'treat': 'maj', 'mat': 'asp', 'class': 'art',
                              'hci': 60, 'cost': 350000},
              'rep_asp_art': {'treat': 'maj', 'mat': 'asp', 'class': 'art',
                              'hci': 0, 'cost': 1000000},
              'min_asp_col': {'treat': 'min', 'mat': 'asp', 'class': 'col',
                              'hci': 85, 'cost': 100000},
              'maj_asp_col': {'treat': 'maj', 'mat': 'asp', 'class': 'col',
                              'hci': 60, 'cost': 350000},
              'rep_asp_col': {'treat': 'maj', 'mat': 'asp', 'class': 'col',
                              'hci': 0, 'cost': 1000000},
              'min_chip_col': {'treat': 'min', 'mat': 'chip', 'class': 'col',
                               'hci': 70, 'cost': 30000},
              'maj_chip_col': {'treat': 'maj', 'mat': 'chip', 'class': 'col',
                               'hci': 50, 'cost': 80000},
              'rep_chip_col': {'treat': 'maj', 'mat': 'chip', 'class': 'col',
                               'hci': 0, 'cost': 100000},
              'min_chip_loc': {'treat': 'min', 'mat': 'chip', 'class': 'loc',
                               'hci': 70, 'cost': 30000},
              'maj_chip_loc': {'treat': 'maj', 'mat': 'chip', 'class': 'loc',
                               'hci': 45, 'cost': 80000},
              'rep_chip_loc': {'treat': 'maj', 'mat': 'chip', 'class': 'loc',
                               'hci': 0, 'cost': 100000},
              }

ndf = pd.DataFrame(treatments)
ndf = ndf.round(3)

dft = ndf.T


def get_treatment(material, func_class, hci):
    return dft[(dft['mat'] == material) &
               (dft['class'] == func_class) &
               (dft['hci'].astype(int) >= hci)].index


test_data = {'a': {'mat': 'asp', 'class': 'art', 'hci': 35},
             'b': {'mat': 'asp', 'class': 'art', 'hci': 90},
             'c': {'mat': 'asp', 'class': 'col', 'hci': 68},
             'd': {'mat': 'asp', 'class': 'art', 'hci': 5},
             'e': {'mat': 'chip', 'class': 'col', 'hci': 55},
             'f': {'mat': 'chip', 'class': 'loc', 'hci': 95},
             'g': {'mat': 'asp', 'class': 'art', 'hci': 15},
             'h': {'mat': 'asp', 'class': 'art', 'hci': 70},
             'i': {'mat': 'asp', 'class': 'art', 'hci': 3}
             }

for k, v in test_data.items():
    res = get_treatment(v['mat'], v['class'], v['hci'])
    print (k, res)


# Output:
# a Index(['min_asp_art', 'maj_asp_art'], dtype='object')
# b Index([], dtype='object')
# c Index(['min_asp_col'], dtype='object')
# d Index(['min_asp_art', 'maj_asp_art'], dtype='object')
# e Index(['min_chip_col'], dtype='object')
# f Index([], dtype='object')
# g Index(['min_asp_art', 'maj_asp_art'], dtype='object')
# h Index(['min_asp_art'], dtype='object')
# i Index(['min_asp_art', 'maj_asp_art'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: @QuangHoang for a: 'rep_asp_art', 1000000

Comment: What's `a`? There's no `a` in your sample data?

Comment: @QuangHoang in test_data 'a', the first one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As such?

```
def get_treatment(material, func_class, hci):
    return dft[(dft['mat'] == material) &
               (dft['class'] == func_class) &
               (dft['hci'].astype(int) >= hci)]['cost']


# test_data = ... #

for k, v in test_data.items():
    res = get_treatment(v['mat'], v['class'], v['hci'])
    print (k, res, '\n')
```

**Output:**

```
> a min_asp_art    100000
> maj_asp_art    350000
> Name: cost, dtype: object 

> b Series([], Name: cost, dtype: object) 

> c min_asp_col    100000
> Name: cost, dtype: object 

> d min_asp_art    100000
> maj_asp_art    350000
> Name: cost, dtype: object 

> e min_chip_col    30000
> Name: cost, dtype: object 

> f Series([], Name: cost, dtype: object) 

> g min_asp_art    100000
> maj_asp_art    350000
> Name: cost, dtype: object 

> h min_asp_art    100000
> Name: cost, dtype: object 

> i min_asp_art    100000
> maj_asp_art    350000
> Name: cost, dtype: object
```